# Matching the unstructured data with a specific list of values through Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, pandas, list

I've a source file as follows:

```html
terr_cd,TenderName,key
840,CREDIT SALES - Uber Eats ,PO002:369837386
840,CREDIT SALES-Skip The Dishes ,P0008:1000955655
840,UberEats,P002:369837388
840,uber-eats,PO002:369837389
840,UBER EATS,P002:369837391
840,ventes cr?dit - Uber Eats,PO02:369837393
840,ventes cr?dit-skip the dishes,PO02:369837394
826,Sp the Dishes,POS002:3697395
826,skiptishes,PO02:3697396
```

I've to match it with a list as mentioned below:

```html
test_list = ['UberEats', 'DoorDash', 'DLV', 'Deliver', 'Skipthedishes']
```

I've to populate a new column named "Flag" which would populated Yes/No is any of the values in my test list matches with the value in my 'TenderName' column through Python.

I've tried implementing it through the code mentioned below:

```html
search = 'CREDIT SALES-Uber Eats'
clean_str = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+','',search)

test_list = ['UberEats', 'DoorDash', 'DLV', 'Deliver', 'Skipthedishes']


for pattern in test_list:
              if re.search(pattern,clean_str):
                             print('yes')
                             break;
              else:
                             print('no')
```

But I'm not able to populate a new column. Can you please provide a solution to this issue. Thanks!

Comment: You haven't tried to create a column anywhere. Where you want to add a column? As it is tagged with pandas, is there any `DataFrame` to which you are trying to add a column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you meant by adding a 'Flag' column, could you clarify that? I am simply giving you a Flag as an output without that clarification.

If your need is to find out if any of the item in test_list exists as a value for TenderName column in the file, this can be solved multiple ways. Since you tagged pandas, I am providing a pandas solution:

```
import pandas as pd

test_list = ['UberEats', 'DoorDash', 'DLV', 'Deliver', 'Skipthedishes']

df=pd.read_csv("FilePath.csv")
flag="No"
for item in test_list:
    if len(df[df["TenderName"]==item]) > 0:
        flag="Yes"
        break

print(flag)
```